# Is it safe/right to use an older version of Google api PHP client library (2.8.3) for Google Wallet api integration

Tags: laravel-4, google-api-php-client, android-pay, google-pay, laravel-4.2

I have an old/big project that is based on Laravel 4.2.
In the wallet samples provided by Google, https://github.com/google-pay/wallet-samples/tree/main/php I can see that the version used in the composer is
"google/apiclient": "^2.12". However, google/apiclient version 2.12 is incompatible with Laravel 4.2 because of the requirement of "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0||^3.0.2" (Laravel 4.2 is only compatible with 0.3.*).
I have therefore throught that I can simply use version https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/v2.8.3 of the library which supports "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~0.3.10||~2.0".

Is it OK to use version 2.8.3 for integration? What are the risks associated with this decision?

Thanks